# how to show limited rows in side menu

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing an app in which I have created side menu for user profile using SWRevealViewController everything works fine till now when I run the app I am getting side menu like this

[image]

It has more number of rows but I have to set limited number of rows like this

[image]

I set a tableViewcontroller as (sw_rear) for swrevealcontroller and I set a uitableviewcontroller class for that tableviewcontroller that class is

```
class UserProfile: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()          

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 2
    }

    /*
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // Override to support editing the table view.
 /**   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    } **/

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

I don't know how to bring that limited rows in my tableViewController can any one help me please ?

Comment: you are fix number of row?

Comment: where do i fix it ?

Comment: number of row always same means your slide menu item 'call support' is same 6 row. that use custom view number of row that same to view.

Comment: how many rows you return ? is it fix ? this cell design on story board ?

Comment: I have 2 prototype cell in my storyboard @ yankit Patel

Comment: Set the tablefooter view zero

Comment: it means your side menu content come dynamically right ?

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy Just add `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)

Comment: it is not footerview issue.

Comment: do I add it in my uitableViewController class @Bhavin Ramani

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy In your `sidebarview` class

Comment: yes it is dynamic content @ yankit Patel

Comment: while I am adding that I get error like "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException " @Bhavin Ramani

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy you should use breakpoint. where the app is crashing? And give full error.

Comment: when the compiler comes to this line self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero) it shows this error   Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],  terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException @ Bhavin Ramani

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy please Put the full error detail here.